# Chrome odd font-size behaviour

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, frontend

Google Chrome (Version 89.0.4389.114, 64-bit) has some strange behaviour when using a `%` value for the `font-size` property.

In stead of the expected behaviour, reducing the font size to a given percentage, it will stop doing so if the calculated font size would be smaller than `6px`, and it will not go below that magic `6px`. FireFox does scale down the font as expected.

Example:

I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0suha73k/17/) in which I scale down the font at the `:root` to `1%`. In both browsers, the default font size is `16px`, so the expected font size is `0.16px`. FireFox does indeed render it as such, Chrome however does not, as the rendered font size is `6px`. An image with FireFox on the left and Chrome on the right to illustrate the issue without you having to fiddle around https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EyTFQ3WWgAA_fL6?format=png&name=large.

So I am wondering, does anyone know how to bypass this?

I need it to work for the `%` unit, as I use it to enable this "rem to px" conversion. By setting `:root`'s `font-size` to `6.25%`, `1rem` will equal `1px` (if the browser's default font size is set to `16px`). This allows me to develop the site in `rem` units without having to deal with conversions all the time. The benefit? The site will now scale perfectly when the user decides to change their default font size to, f.e., `20px`.

I haven't found a workaround *yet*, so any ideas are much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Sounds too small to read! but you could try `calc(1% * 1)` or something to see if that gets around the limit?

Comment: Similar, though not exactly the same, discussion here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53856831/rem-font-size-not-adjusting-below-arbitrary-threshold - 6px seems to be a lower limit for Chrome.

Comment: @Damon, that sadly doesn't work :(

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks for the link, that clears up some stuff. Sadly no solution in the comments. At least it gives me some peace of mind, knowing it is not my fault ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of Chrome designed to prevent font sizes from becoming illegibly small. Chrome cannot assume that the developer will always restore the font size to a readable value using a multiplier, so it enforces a minimum size.

The conventional way to adjust font sizes for easy rem calculations is by setting the base font size to 62.5%, not 6.25% or 1%, then use rems in x.y increments:

```css
:root {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.foo {
  font-size: 1.2rem; /* 12px */
}
```

See [CSS fonts rem trick: 62.5% or 6.25%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923397/css-fonts-rem-trick-62-5-or-6-25/47923518#47923518)

Comment: Indeed a good workaround, sadly it would require me to add decimal points everywhere in my code base, so a bit of a hassle. Thanks for the suggestion, will certainly think of using this in the future instead!